# MySQL, PHP filtering results within displayed table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, filter, html-table

I've searched through what "I think I should be searching for" - but not really understanding or getting anywhere, please could someone point me in the right direction?

I'd like to be able to filter a result set using the `th` of one column (region) and although I tried the w3cs tutorial I ended up confusing myself as to "what bit of code goes where" etc and the dropdown form thingie looked very clunky.
All advice and help most welcome.

This is my example website, [myTrader](http://www.palegallery.com/Reassessment) clicking the All Trade Regions link on the left displays as far as I've got & that took me days of cobbling tutorials and guddling about in the dark.

query.php code so far:

```
    <table id="mainTable">
    <tr><td width="300" valign="top"><H1>Welcome to myTrader!</H1>
    <span class="mainText">Glass & Paper Recycled Commodities Trading Site</span></td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"><img src="images/largeLogo.jpg" width="406" height="113" border="0"></td></tr></table>
    <P><span class="paraHeadingOne">All Region Paper Sales</span> </P>
    <P>
    <table class="dbTable">
<tr>
<tr><th>Commodity</th> <th>Region</th> <th>Member</th> <th>Size</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Date Posted</th>
</tr>
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'palegall', '******');
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('palegall_newTrader', $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('cant find newTrader' . mysql_error());
    }
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `sell` WHERE `commodity`='Paper' ORDER BY `price`") or die( mysql_error() );
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    do
    {
    echo'<table class="dbTable">';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['commodity'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['region'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['member'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['size'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['price'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['posted'].'</td>
   </tr>';
    }while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
  </td></tr></table>
  </td></tr></table>
  </body></html>
```

Comment: We need more information : what tables have you created ? what results do you want ? provide a short example (an entire website is not an example)...

Comment: Sorry Scorpi0 - only want to use the two tables displayed - (sell & buy) - all the data needs to appear first, then have the user click the header for Region & some method of filtering be available, I dont have any code for the filter part yet but can post my query.php code here - erm, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To filter results you need to add `WHERE columnName = 'desiredValue'` at the end of the query. Optionally, you can specify several conditions using `AND` or `OR`, for example:

```
 WHERE columnName = 'possibleValue' OR columnName = 'otherPossibleValue'
```

Comment: Hello EdoDodo - thank you, as above I need all the results to show first then for the user to be able to filter them - so Im guessing I need two queries, the first to show me all results, & a second one (which is where I dont know where to put or how to construct) would my second query "live" on the same page as the results?  Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean,
have you tried playing around with the WHERE area of the query. This can change how many results are returned.
I had something similar to this, except it was tagged locations. I had two ideas, first, a table with each column of a tinyint, each one was a certain area. Or the other, where there was just one extra column with space delimited values for specific areas. That was the one I went for and used a query similar to

```
SELECT * FROM 'items' WHERE `locations` LIKE '% $area %'
```

as long as there was always a space at the beginning of the string, it was fine at it allowed for multiple options for a single item which didn't take a load of queries to load and lots of memory to sift through the data.

in this case, the data included was

ID    Title        locations
1      Test 1    *blank*
2      Test 2     london surrey

When a search was done for just london, then "test 2" was displayed

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello Chris thank you, I need all the results to show first, then have the user click to select a region, Ive tried using separate links but its very clunky, just wondered if there is an "in table" way of filtering? Or something to add (as suggested below although not tried it yet!) - :)

Comment: do you mean AJAX? because you could just get it to repopulate the target area with a new table loaded from a PHP file with a GET variable of the target area. Even if its not ajax, you could have a general query that has no WHERE tag and displays them all, with separate links or a text box at the top (under the column headers) where certain areas can be searched for. You would need to have some kind of anti sql injection code active to protect your database.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks - yes I think thats kinda what Im after? I looked at two tutorials that included an ajax drop down thing & implemented script on the query page, (I couldnt get it to work) I didnt really understand where to "put" stuff in relation to the querys etc on the page - sorry for being a bit slow on the uptake!  Basically I just want a simpe user click & allow them to select region - not fussed how, so long as I can get it to work LOL,

Comment: - also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306807/php-filtering-data-in-table :)

Comment: well, either have a dropdown select box that is populated with the list of areas, or a text box for searching. That could be in the next row from the table headers, then have a second table below in a div tag with an ID of new content, then use getElementById('newcontent') to change the inner html with the AJAX response. The call is made when either a button is clicked, or a change has been made with no changes in the last 2 seconds. This sends off a request to '/newcontent.php?searchfield=' then the contents of the text box or select. The PHP then takes that, SQL's it and returns a table

Comment: OK...so if I aim for the dropdown & I only want the region <th> to have it can I simply shove the dropdown "options" code bit into where <th> region header is? I dont understand (sorry) why I need a separate table below - can the table itself not update in realtimte since I need all the regions displayed first, then user filter.  I dont want the orginal data to remain above in a sep table? - (you've ended up with the muppet here - my apologies)

Comment: I wouldn't stick it in the <th>, but rather create a new <tr> with the same number of <td>'s. then after that a </table> and then a brand new table in a <div> tag with identical widths and spacings so they line up.

You need a second table because you would need a repeater to go through the returned code from the PHP script, and insert/remove rows from the table. Its just simpler to clear all the data, and reinsert it from scratch. Its just faster and requires less code.

Comment: ...ok Chris - that sounds logical & I'll give it a go, really appreciate your advice & help - will shout back with how I get on - many thanks!!!

Comment: Good luck, if there are still any other lingering issues, drop us a line

Comment: ...oh trust me - Ill be your horrible stalker until I get this sorted out - it was for one of my 2nd year uni modules (which since I failed first time Im capped at 40% & if I dont get that Im out) After waiting until my age to be able to get to uni, I'll be gutted! Generally I just make pretty designs, not back end stuff! :)

Comment: ...I wondered if I should add another question to this since its relevant to above or begin a new thread? - Im quite new & dont want to get into trouble lol!